# strsplit on first instance

Tags: regex, r, strsplit

I would like to write a strsplit command that grabs the first ")" and splits the string.

For example:

```
f("12)34)56")
"12" "34)56"
```

I have read over several other related regex SO questions but I am afraid I am not able to make heads or tails of this. Thank you any assistance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could get the same list-type result as you would with `strsplit` if you used `regexpr` to get the first match, and then the inverted result of `regmatches`.

```
x <- "12)34)56"
regmatches(x, regexpr(")", x), invert = TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "12"    "34)56"
```

Answer (score 13):

Need speed? Then go for `stringi` functions. See timings e.g. [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263571/r-fast-string-split-on-first-delimiter-occurence).

```
library(stringi)
x <- "12)34)56"
stri_split_fixed(str = x, pattern = ")", n = 2)
```

Answer (score 7):

It might be safer to identify where the character is and then substring either side of it:

```
x <- "12)34)56"
spl <- regexpr(")",x)
substring(x,c(1,spl+1),c(spl-1,nchar(x)))
#[1] "12"    "34)56"
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use `str_split` in the package `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
f <- function(string)
{
  unlist(str_split(string,"\\)",n=2))
}
> f("12)34)56")
[1] "12"    "34)56"
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace the first `(` with the non-printing character `"\01"` and then strsplit on that.  You can use any character you like in place of `"\01"` as long as it does not appear.

```
strsplit(sub(")", "\01", "12)34)56"), "\01")
```

Comment: Thanks to the suggestion but this is dangerous because in general there might be a comma before the `)` such as `strsplit(sub(")", ",", ",12)34)56"), ",")`.