# Use strsplit with multiple delimiters

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

How can I split this

```
 Chr3:153922357-153944632(-)
 Chr11:70010183-70015411(-)
```

in to

```
    Chr3  153922357 153944632 - 
    Chr11 70010183  70015411  -
```

I tried `strsplit(df$V1,"[[:punct:]]"))`, but the negative sign is not coming in the final result

Comment: (I think) I accidentally deleted a valid post below (not mine)! My deepest apologies! I can't remember who's it was. I flagged this for the mod's attention to undelete.

Comment: You want to split only on the first occurrence of `-`. Perhaps some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246095/r-strsplit-on-first-instance) may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try `str_split` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
lapply(str_split(df$V1, "(?<!\\()\\-|[:\\)\\(]"), function(x) x[x != ""])
```

**Result:**

```
[[1]]
[1] "Chr3"      "153922357" "153944632" "-"        

[[2]]
[1] "Chr11"    "70010183" "70015411" "-"
```

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text = " Chr3:153922357-153944632(-)
 Chr11:70010183-70015411(-) ")
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `-` is both a character you want to extract and a delimiter. Your best bet is using capture groups and specifying the full regex string:

`stringr::str_match(x, "^(.{4}):(\\d+)-(\\d+)\\((.)\\)$")`

EDIT: If you want to let the first capture group capture strings of arbitrary length (e.g. ChrX for any X), you can change first capture group from `.{4}` to `Chr\\d+`.

Comment: if i use stringr::str_match(x, "^(.{4}):(\\d+)-(\\d+)\\((.)\\)$"), the second row is getting NA

Comment: Regex should cover cases for ChrNNA, i.e.: chr1, chr12, chrX.

Answer (score 2):

How about this in base R using `stringsplit` and `gsub`:

```
# Your sample strings
ss <- c("Chr3:153922357-153944632(-)",
        "Chr11:70010183-70015411(-)")

# Split items as list of vectors 
lst <- lapply(ss, function(x)
    unlist(strsplit(gsub("(.+):(\\d+)-(\\d+)\\((.)\\)", "\\1,\\2,\\3,\\4", x), ",")))


# rbind to dataframe if necessary
do.call(rbind, lst);
#    [,1]    [,2]        [,3]        [,4]
#[1,] "Chr3"  "153922357" "153944632" "-"
#[2,] "Chr11" "70010183"  "70015411"  "-"
```

This should work for other chromosome names and positive strand features as well.